# How to update a live PHP5 to PHP7 application

Tags: deployment, php-5.5, php-7

Our company has a "legacy" PHP app, developed by another developer over a decade. It's running on a server with PHP5.5.

What would be a best-practice approach of moving that live application to a PHP7 environment?

Testing would have to happen on PHP7 in a development environment for sure. But my question is for the live switchover. Do you upgrade the server's PHP version and deploy the new version of the application at the same time?

Comment: You can install and run both PHP versions at the same time, i.e. run php5-fpm and php7-fpm on different ports and then switch the port in the nginx config (or redirect a part of the traffic for testing).

Comment: It's Apache, no nginx.